# "The social network" quote

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the film "The Social Network" Mark Zuckerberg gets caught and presented before Harvard's administrative board. They say he deserved some recognition for pointing out holes in their network security and Harvard's IT guy says they were fast in catching Zuckerberg in less than four hours.

Then Zuckerberg quipped "that would be impressive except if they had known what they were looking for,they would have seen it written on my dorm room window".

I don't understand this sentence? I know it's grammar and is a closed conditional but can someone please explain exactly what Zuckerberg means to say here?

Answer (score 1):

In this scene, Zuckerberg is referring to a previous scene where he used his window-pane as a dry erase board to work out the equations required. So he means that if the IT department was alert and knew what sort of holes their system had, they could have noticed the equations literally written on the window of his dormitory and understood what he was planning.

Now, it's a movie and that claim is ridiculous. Even if an IT professional understood a potential vulnerability and knew what math it would take to exploit it, seeing related equations on a student's bedroom window would not alert the professional. The student might just be in a related mathematics class. Or the student might be working on something else entirely. Furthermore, most IT staff members do not regularly walk through residential areas of campus.

But I hope that I helped you understand what Zuckerberg's character was trying to say.

Comment: Though the equations were for the algorithm that ranked girls.they are unrelated to holes that Harvard's servers had.

Comment: You're right actually. That just makes the comment even more rediculous